# CSS `clear: both;` property inside body

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am reading *HTML and CSS* and I produced the following code.

```css
   body { 
    width: 752px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #665544;
   }
   div {
    border: 1px solid #665544;
   }
   p {
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
   }
   .clear {
    clear: both;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Parent Float - Problem</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>The Evolution of the Bicycle</h1>
  <div>
   <p class="one">In 1817 Baron von Drais invented a walking machine that would help him get around the royal gardens faster.</p>
   <p class="two">The device know as the Draisienne (or "hobby horse") was made of wood, and propelled by pushing your feed on the ground in a gliding movement.</p>
   <p class="three">It was not seen a suitable for any place other than a well maintained pathway. </p>
   <p class="four clear">In 1865, the velocipede (meaning "fast foot") attached pedals to the front wheel, but its wooden structure made it extremely uncomfortable.</p>
   <p class="five>In 1870 the first all-metal machine appeared. The pedals were attached directly to the front wheel. 
   <p class="six">Solid rubber tires and the long spokes of the large front wheel provided a much smoother ride than its predecessor.</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now, I applied the CSS rule `clear: both;` to the paragraph with class `clear`. 
However, I can see that the left hand side does not touch any other element inside the `body` container, but why does it still touch paragraph `five` on the right hand side?

***EDIT*** The book I am reading shows no mention of `clear` only applying to preceding elements -

[image]

Comment: Because paragraph five comes after it. Clearing only is with respect to elements that come before the element being cleared. ["The floats that are relevant to be cleared are the earlier floats within the same block formatting context."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Comment: @j08691 so what is the difference then between `clear: left` and `clear: both`?

Comment: `clear:left` will clear any previous element that was floated left where `clear:both` will clear any previous elements that were floated left or right. You can see in the [spec here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-clear) how it refers to elements appearing earlier in the document. "...floating boxes that resulted from elements earlier in the source document"

Comment: I'm trying to read the text in the screenshot, but I have no idea what they're trying to say. The [W3C Wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear) is much more, ehm, clear.

Comment: @MrLister all I can say is, I was reading the book and it got me very confused! Thanks anyway!